# Xen vs KVM vulnerability frequency and disclosure

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm

It seems like there's a new XSA every month. Amazon have rolling EC2 blackouts whenever they have to update Xen for a critical security issue. Linode moved from Xen to KVM partially for the security benefits.

But, i don't know of any XSA-alike reporting system for KVM. Maybe KVM just gets less security attention since it's not yet the #1 market player. Certainly many qemu vulnerabilities impact both Xen and KVM.

My question is:

Does Xen's greater rate of disclosed vulnerabilities indicate less secure code than KVM, or, does it only indicate greater scrutiny?

Comment: The answer to this would be too opinion based. Both ofthe two opinions you have put forth are valid. All I can say is secure coding is an ideal scenario. Better scrutiny would means well matured code over a period of time.